# Format servlet cookie to http-friendly format

Tags: java, http, servlets, cookies

Given a javax.servlet.http.Cookie object, is there a method somewhere that can format the cookie to http friendly format so I can send it in the response? Likewise, given a cookie header in request, is there a method to parse the cookie into a javax.servlet.http.Cookie object? I've looked all over but couldn't find a method that does that.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean you just want to handle `cookies`?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing my implementation of java servlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HttpCookie](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html) class for your own implementation. Use its `toString()` function to

`Constructs a cookie header string representation of this cookie, which is in the format defined by corresponding cookie specification, but without the leading "Cookie:" token.`

After this add header `Set-Cookie:THE_TO_STRING_VALUE` to the response and that's it.

For reading the cookies back you need to parse the `headers`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clearly state my question. I am actually implementing my own servlet container. So I am implementing all relevant classes such as HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse. Thus, I need to manually create the response headers myself.

Comment: @Jin check it out i have changed the answer. Hope that helps. :)